# Finding the average of every sublist in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to get the average of every sublist of a list:
the original list is [5,[1,2],[3,4,5]], and want to get this list: [5, 1.5, 4].
For firstly calculating the average, I tried:

```
l = [5,[1,2],[3,4,5]]   
for x in l:
    sum(x)/len(x)
```

but it reports:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 2, in <module>
  TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How should I get the average of sublists and write it in a list?

Comment: `5` is not a list and `sum(5)` is an error, as `sum()` expects an iterable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you must actually sum over a list object, you can do

```
l = [5,[1,2],[3,4,5]]
averages = []
for x in l:
    x_ = x if type(x) is list else [x]
    #averages += [sum(x_)/float(len(x_))] # I turn the length into a float since you do not mention your version of Python
    averages.append(sum(x_)/float(len(x_)))
```

Which outputs

```
[5.0, 1.5, 4.0]
```

Comment: Creating a new list  just so you can use the `+=` operator seems unnecessary, just `.append()` - `averages.append(...)`

Comment: @AChampion. You are right. It is a reflex since `+=`  is about 15% faster when one does not create the list, ~50% slower *a contrario*.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [5,[1,2],[3,4,5]]   
#use the isinstance method to check if the element is a list or not and deal with differently.
for x in l:
    print(sum(x)/(len(x)*1.0) if isinstance(x,list) else x)

5
1.5
4.0
```

If you don't mind using another package, you can do:

```
import numpy as np
#map np.mean method to each sublist of the list to calculate mean.
map(np.mean,l)
Out[99]: [5.0, 1.5, 4.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first element in `l` is `5` which is an `int` and not a `list` hence the error.

```
l = [[5],[1,2],[3,4,5]]   
for x in l:
    sum(x)/len(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [5,[1,2],[3,4,5]]   
j = []
for x in l:
  if type(x) is list:
    j.append(sum(list(x))/len(x))
  else:
    j.append(x)

print(j)
```